# Slecting specific query returnned data related records from another table

Tags: sql-server, query, subquery

Product table:

```
productId | productName | unitPrice | supplierId
_______________________________________________
    1     | Iphone8     | 1500      |     3
    2     | Nokia 6     | 800       |     1
    3     | Samsung S9  | 1500      |     2
```

Supplier table:

```
supplierId | supplierName | country
___________________________________
     1     | Nokia Inc    | India
     2     | Samsung Inc  | Korea
     3     | Apple Inc    | USA
```

I’m confused, how can I write a query using above two `Product` and `Supplier` tables to list the product unitprice 1500 only and their supplier `Id`, `name` and `country`. Such as the table below shows.

```
    productId | unitPrice| supplierId |supplierName | country
    _____________________________________________
        1     |   1500   |     3      | Apple Inc   | USA
        3     |   1500   |     2      | Samsung Inc | Korea
```

I used join queries with `supplierId` on `product` table to get its relating data from the `supplier` table. But each time I ended up in error when I try to fetch '= 1500' to this query.

this is the query I tried;

```
select *
from Product, Supplier
where Product.supplierId = Supplier.supplierId
```

but it gives all the records, how can I insert "unitPrice = 1500" to this query to achieve my answer?

Comment: Add `WHERE unitPrice = 1500` at the end

Comment: Noh, I tried, it doesn't work, gives error '' Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'." @Jacob H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this give you the desired results.

```
--demo setup
DECLARE @ProductTable TABLE (
  productId INTEGER,
  productName VARCHAR(10),
  unitPrice INTEGER,
  supplierId INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO @ProductTable
  (productId, productName, unitPrice, supplierId)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Iphone8', '1500', '3'),
  ('2', 'Nokia 6', '800', '1'),
  ('3', 'Samsung S9', '1500', '2');

DECLARE @SupplierTable TABLE (
  supplierId INTEGER,
  supplierName VARCHAR(11),
  country VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO @SupplierTable
  (supplierId, supplierName, country)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Nokia Inc', 'India'),
  ('2', 'Samsung Inc', 'Korea'),
  ('3', 'Apple Inc', 'USA');

--solution
SELECT p.productId
    ,p.unitPrice
    ,p.supplierId
    ,s.supplierName
    ,s.country
FROM @ProductTable P
JOIN @SupplierTable s
    ON s.supplierId = P.supplierId
where p.unitPrice=1500
order by p.productId
```

---

```
| productId | unitPrice | supplierId | supplierName | country |
|-----------|-----------|------------|--------------|---------|
| 1         | 1500      | 3          | Apple Inc    | USA     |
| 3         | 1500      | 2          | Samsung Inc  | Korea   |
```

Comment: Yes it does, but all the data of tables have to be entered to the query sounds difficult as if there many records in tables, Is there any ways to retrieve data from specific tables(Product & Supplier) to declared tables without entering data  in query? @Scott Hodgin

Comment: @Aaby- I merely used table variables `@Product` and `@Suppliers` to demo my solution.  Look at my answer starting at the comment `--solution` and replace my table variables with your real tables.

Comment: Yes, I got it.. :) Thank you so much genius..@Scott Hodgin